# How did Chewbacca get a roast Porg?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, chewbacca

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, Chewbacca is seen cooking what is apparently a porg over an open flame. He starts to eat it but then notices several porg watching him with looks of fear. Out of disgust or guilt he decides not to eat the bird. How did he get one to start cooking it in the first place?

1. Did he kill and prepare it himself? This is the implication but seems odd considering the above. If that didn't bother him, why would he have had any problem with eating it?
2. Did one of the natives (the temple guardians) sell it to him, already prepared? Perhaps Luke killed it and gave it to Chewie.
3. Maybe it wasn't a porg, but was some other kind of less intelligent bird?

Comment: FWIW, the scene does not match with the (also indicated to be canon) book, *Chewie and the Porgs* (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewie_and_the_Porgs)

Comment: 1. He may not have seen it's *cute little face* when he killed it and cooked it. 2. I'm pretty sure he has it over a fire so the implication is that he killed and cooked it. 3. Looks like a porg to me

Comment: He's also fine eating the porgs when the group are watching him, it's when the one on it's own gives him puppy eyes that he can't.

Comment: @zabeus "less intelligent bird" Do we know for certain that porgs are any more intelligent, say than chicken?

Comment: @Loki No, not really! I've heard that chickens can be surprisingly smart.

Comment: @zabeus A smart chicken is still a chicken... Mandatory Abstruse Goose comic: https://abstrusegoose.com/314

Comment: What?! He killed it, he roasted it and then, he doesn’t eat it? Does that make the animal alive again? What a waste.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### He picked up a porg, killed it and cooked it.

> Building a fire had taken longer than he’d expected—the island had few
> trees, just stubborn shrubs kept stunted by the ceaseless wind. **At
> least the pudgy native birds—Luke had said they were called porgs—were
> easy to catch. Eager for a change from shipboard rations, Chewbacca
> had scooped one up to roast on a spit.**
>
> **The Wookiee gave the spit another turn and took a sniff.**
>
> **Done. Nicely charred, with a hint of spiciness from the firewood.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Last Jedi: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Comment: Very definitive! Still have to wonder why he cared enough to stop eating then.

Comment: They made him feel bad by looking at him with their big puppy-dog eyes

Answer (score 20):

1. The implication is Chewbacca killed it. We see multiple Porgs by themselves so it's likely he simply saw one and killed it to eat. Given that we see some in the Falcon later, it's possible one wandered in to make a nest and met its end there before Chewbacca changed his mind about them.
2. We never see the guardians or Luke eat Porgs. Based on other scenes (including deleted), they seem to prefer fish.

   [image: Luke carrying a fish]
   [image: Guardian gutting a fish]
3. The clear implication is it's a Porg. It's the right size  and the juxtaposition of them in this frame is clearly meant for comedic effect.

   [image: Roast prog in front of other porgs]

If it's not a porg he's eating, why put it down just because they were looking at him?

Comment: 3. He doesn't stop eating when the group look at him, only when the one on it's own gives him puppy eyes.

Comment: 2. Chewie has the roast porg over a fire, the implication being that he killed and cooked it.

Comment: I suppose *Chewie and the Porgs* isn't **explicitly** out of canon with this, but it toes the line. (https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chewie_and_the_Porgs)